# "back me up on it" or "back me up this"?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, pronouns

Tell me please which word it is correct to use in the following sentence and why.

> I think we should watch that movie, and I hope you back me up on **it**/**this**.

Comment: Are the two of you trying to convince a third person? If not, you're not using "back me up" correctly.   It doesn't matter, "it" or "this" would be OK.

Comment: Yes, what I meant is in this hypothetical situation I wanted a friend of mine to side with me to watch the movie because there was one person who did not want to watch the movie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with TRomano's comment.

Essentially, you are saying:

> I think we should watch that movie, and I hope you back me up on **my idea**.

You could use the pronouns *it, this,* or *that* as a substitute for "my idea". For example:

> I think we should watch that movie, and I hope you back me up on **that**.

Either of your versions would work, too.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope You can also drop the final part of the sentence altogether and simply conclude with *and I hope you back me up.*